# Python unknown infinite loop

Tags: python

Currently I'm doing a programming course and I'm stuck on this question. When I click submit it says there is an infinite loop, I've tested this for hours on and end and can't seem to find it.

```
import re
text = ""
print("Hello, my name is Eliza. What would you like to talk about?")
while text != "go away":
  if text != "go away":
    text = input()
    text = text.lower()
    if re.search(r"\bfeel\b", text) is not None:
      print("Do you often feel that way?")
    elif re.search(r"\bi am\b", text) is not None:
      m = str(re.findall('i am\w* (\w+)',text))
      m = re.sub('[\'\]\[]', '', m)
      print("How long have you been",m+"?")
    elif "you" in text:
        if "me" in text:
          m = str(re.findall('you\w* (\w.*)',text))
          m = m.replace("me","you")
          m = re.sub('[\'?\]\[]', '', m)
          print("What makes you think I",m+"?")
        else:
          print("Please go on")
    elif text == "go away":
      text = "go away"
      break
    else:
      print("Please go on")
  else:
    text = "go away"

print("I hope I have helped you!")
```

This is the error it gives me.

> Your program produced too much output! This is probably because of an infinite loop in your code.

Comment: Whats the input that causes the loop?

Comment: Your code is way too dense and nested. ([Five levels of nesting is too much.](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/01/flattening-arrow-code.html) Although my personal record in code I've seen is eleven.) Simplify it as much as possible while still getting the error then tell us what you found. (Very likely you'll have found the error because it was in something you deleted though.)

Comment: E.g. the `text = "go away"` stuff could be handled by an early return from a function.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has some redundancies, but it works for me.  There are some important differences between python versions 2 and 3, so you should specify that (in particular, for the functions `input()` and `raw_input()`.  I'm running your code with python 2, so I gave strings to the input prompt.

```
Hello, my name is Eliza. What would you like to talk about?
"hi, I am askewchan"
('How long have you been', 'askewchan?')
"go away"
I hope I have helped you!
```

This is an example of a redundancy:

```
while text != "go away":
    if text != "go away":
        ...
    else:
        text = "go away"
```

The first if will always be true, since the while loop only continues if text != "go away".  There is no need for this if-else statement.

Answer (score 1):

So - there is a major logic error here:

You have a loop that keeps going while text != "go away". However, the first thing you check is text != "go away". This is redundant, you just checked that.

I think the reason it does not work though, is a problem with input(). It seems that it is not prompting you.

Comment: The `input()` call is inside the loop, so `text` can be changed and the loop can break.

Comment: input must not be stopping the user and asking, though. Edited, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

All the other answers point out problems in your code, and they're right... but they don't explain the result you're getting from (what appears to be) an automated code judge.

The only way your program fails to terminate is if it never encounters `'go away'` in the input. Note that it has to be *exactly* `'go away'`. If there is extra whitespace, it won't match. For example, `'go away '` won't terminate your program. And maybe the automated judge is feeding your program some unexpected whitespace (which could also conceivably result from an issue with mismatched line endings).

You can guard against this scenario by stripping off extraneous whitespace from the received input. For example, you could change

```
text = input()
```

to

```
text = input().strip()
```

See if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

In

```
while text != "go away":
    if text != "go away":
        # ...
    else:
        text = "go away"
```

, we've already established that `text != "go away"`. This code is no good.